# How to get the "ID" of element by the name with asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, post

I have a generic code that create a loop on the post values. and i need to get the id of the element that posted the data.

For Example, if the Html source is:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
   <input id="Name" type="text" name="Full Name" runat="server" />
   <input id="Email" type="text" name="Email Address" runat="server" />
   <input id="Phone" type="text" name="Phone Number" runat="server" />
</form>
```

C# code:

```
for (int i = 1; i < Request.Form.Count; ++i)
{
    string Value = Request.Form[i];
    if (Value != "")
    {
        string ControlName = Request.Form.Keys[i];
        string ControlId = ""; // Here I need to find the Id
    }
}
```

If the ControlName is: "Full Name", In ControlId I need to get: "Name" etc.

Any advice is welcome.

Comment: FYI: http://geekswithblogs.net/mahesh/archive/2006/06/27/83264.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Request.Form** just returns **NameValueCollection**.

If you want to retrieve controls inside the form as Server controls, you need to use **Page.Form**.

```
foreach (var control in Page.Form.Controls)
{
    if (control is HtmlInputControl)
    {
        var htmlInputControl = control as HtmlInputControl;
        string controlName = htmlInputControl.Name;
        string controlId = htmlInputControl.ID;
    }
}
```